# webpack-dev-server errors with "command not found: webpack-dev-server"

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server

don't really see why I can't get this to run... I've done the following.

```
npm install -g webpack webpack-dev-server
```

confirmed that both installed successfully.

Now, when I try and execute `webpack-dev-server`, I get the following:

```
$ webpack-dev-server --inline --hot
zsh: command not found: 'webpack-dev-server'
```

Never run into this as all my other npm modules load/run fine, both locally and globally. I've tried installing it locally to a project as well (adding to package.json, npm install, yadda yadda..) and receive the same error.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Same thing happening to me right now on Ubuntu. It worked on Mac a few hours ago....

Comment: @jmacedo weird! Glad to know it's not just user error. Maybe they pushed a broken update *shrug* anyone else have any input?

Comment: any solution for the problem?

Comment: @IliyaReyzis yes! please see accepted answer, a solution was found. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a solution as per [this answer on GitHub](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/319#issuecomment-159556054):

> I was able to solve this problem on my machine. It appears to have been an issue with permissions.
>
> I installed `webpack` and `webpack-dev-server` globally. However, even then, `$ webpack-dev-server` resulted in command not found (as stated above).
>
> The problem was that npm installed the global packages to `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` which required root permissions.
>
> In order to avoid having to use root permissions, I changed the directory in which global packages are to be installed to a directory in `$HOME`. To do this, I followed this guide: https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/master/npm-global-without-sudo.md
>
> I installed `webpack` and `webpack-dev-server` globally again (this time without sudo) and verified that they have been installed in my new directory.
>
> Now, I can finally run `$ webpack-dev-server`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that npm installs the global packages to /usr/local/lib/node_modules which requires root permissions.
To avoid this you can use Use **sudo npm i -g webpack webpack-dev-server**.

It worked for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.